# Do recursive functions use twice as much memory as their iterative counterparts in C, in most cases?

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, factorial, space-complexity

```
 // Recursive Implementation:
int factorialResult(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return factorialResult(n - 1) * n;
    }
}



// Iterative Implementation:
int factorialResult(int n) {
    int factorialSum = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        factorialSum *= i;
    }

    return factorialSum;
}
```

In most cases in C, do recursive function implementations use more memory? And if so, is it around double the memory of a corresponding iterative function implementation?

Comment: The factor is not univerally two, that's for sure.  It depends on the recursive function.  And it depends on how the non-recursive function works.  Tail recursion is trivially replaceable by iteration.  Other recursive functions use stack space for the local variables on each call — but may be much simpler to understand and implement than the non-recursive equivalent.

Comment: In recursive solutions, the size of the function and its data goes on the stack for Each recursive call -- so it can amount to much more than double the memory used.  In fact, in the pathological situation of a runaway recursive function calling itself repeatedly, you can run out of stack space real quick -- and that's known as stack overflow (yes, like this website ).

Comment: You can find recursive implementations using the same or even less memory than an iterative implementation. But although I don't have statistical proof, I think a recursive function will typically use more memory. But to say that it is approximately double is completely wrong.

Comment: A benefit of recursion is _backtracking_. The program's stack stores _state_ for using variations that can be explored by deeper levels. It's often less obvious how to achieve that using iteration... (The point is, does the code work and is it understandable?)

Comment: No, not always. How you would count "most cases" is unclear. Counter examples are Divide-and-conquer algorithms: their average stack use would be O(log).

Answer (score 2):

In your factorial implementations, no heap memory space is used, so in that respect, the two are identical. Where they *may* differ is in stack space usage.

The recursive solution is O(n) in stack space usage, while the iterative solution uses constant stack space. Given enough recursive calls, the recursive solution may yield a stack overflow error.

There are a few provisos here:

1. Your compiler *may* implement tail-call optimization, where if the last (or "tail") call in your function is simply another function call, the compiler may be able to convert it to a simple loop.

E.g.

```
int factorialResult_tailRec(int n, int acc) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return acc;
    }
    else {
        return factorialResult_tailRec(n - 1, acc * n);
    }
}
```

Where this is called as `factorialResult_tailRec(5, 1)`.

However, this optimization should not be counted upon.

2. Consider carefully your data types. You may overflow `int` before you ever encounter a stack overflow. For instance, 13! already overflows a 32-bit `int`, but those recursive calls will have no substantial effect on stack space. Even if you expand your data to a 64-bit integer, 21! still overflows and has no significant effect on stack space.

Answer (score 0):

Not "twice as much" memory, but on the order of `n` times as much memory is likely used.

All of this memory is stack memory.  Stack memory is cheap to allocate compared to heap memory. A stack allocation takes O(1) time - it just moves the stack pointer.

But it's limited. Threads usually have a megabyte of stack on high-end computers to about 100KB on low-end devices. Depends on compiler settings and OS architecture.  So if you invoked the recursive `factorial(500000)`, it would hit a literal "stack overflow" error long before the overflowed result could be returned to the caller.